# Problem installing pecl install sqlsrv on macbook M1

Tags: php, apple-m1, pecl, macos-monterey

I need to install `sqlsrv-5.8.1` on a MacBook with an M1.
I installed:

- php7.3
- httpd
- openssl

And when I want to install sqlsrv via the command `pecl install sqlsrv-5.8.1` I have an error:

`ERROR: 'make' failed`

With a command:

`sudo CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib/" pecl install sqlsrv-5.8.1`

I have an error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [sqlsrv.la] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Do you have an idea to install version 5.8.1 ???

Comment: In the title to your post what do you mean by `installing pecl sqlsrv`? Are you trying to install the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server? If so, according to [Release Notes for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/release-notes-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16), v5.10 states _Added support for Apple M1 ARM64 hardware. Requires ODBC Driver 17.8 or above._. However, it also states _Dropped support for PHP 7.3._.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install sqlsrv for php.
Is there a solution to install the sqlsrv (version 5.8.1) with php7.3?

Comment: The tag `sqlsrv` refers to Microsoft SQL Server which is a relational database management system. See [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads). According to [Determine the version, edition, and update level of SQL Server and its components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/determine-version-edition-update-level) the earliest version of SQL Server that exists is v6.5 which was created prior to the year 2000. It seems that you may be using incorrect terminology which is leading to confusion.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).